# Look up to Master-detail through MetaData API: "cannot add master-detail relationship due to existing data rows"

Tags: lookup, sharing, relationships, master-detail

Trying to change the existing relation between A(Parent) and B(Child) from Look up to Master- Detail. Deploying "B__c.A__c" using ANT.

- Ran a query on B and made sure all B__c.A__c is populated (As per the documentation, if all look up fields are populated, we can convert relation from lookup to master-detail)

During deployment, I am getting error "cannot add master-detail relationship due to existing data rows"

Any idea on resolving this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you also check the recycle bin? You must purge or restore and correct all records, even those in a deleted status.

Comment: Did "Empty Organization recyclebin" as this is sandbox but still getting same error when validating

Comment: It might be some sort of time delay between purging and when you can deploy. I don't know why else that error would happen. Try it again later? Hopefully you get this resolved.

Comment: Earlier I tried to do this manually as well. It said "Updating records. We will send email once completed". It has been more than 24 hours but neither get any email nor did the relationship change. So tried using ANT but got the above error message

Comment: since i emptied recycle bin will try to do this again. Thanks sfdcfox. Will comment here the status later.

Comment: Once you do empty recycle bin ur records should be deleted. But after this there is physical delete which is done by Salesforce. That process takes time because of which you might be getting this error. You can fasten up physical deletion by raising a case. I got this information from Salesforce support about physical delete.

Comment: @sfdcfox.. It worked !!!!  I think it took some time to empty recycle bin but i tried to deploy now and it worked. Never thought even records in recyclebin matter to change the relation type. Thanks sfdcfox :)

Comment: If you want to answer this yourself, go ahead. I don't care for the rep.

Comment: you please go ahead and answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check records in recyclebin as well.
" You must purge or restore and correct all records, even those in a deleted status"